# Show woocommerce orders by country

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using WooCommerce for my Wordpress site, and I need a section where my client can see orders by specific shipping countries. I tried to create new role for him and that will show him needed orders but I didn't find solution yet.

Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can I get orders by specific shipping countries on my frontend page?

Comment: can we see what have you tried so far?

Comment: you want that for front-end users or back-end users ?
Please clarify that and show us what you have tried till now

Answer (score 1):

Ive answered similar question found here.
If you want to query orders by specific country code.
Try this snippet.

```
// If you want to get orders from America.
$args = array(
    'billing_country' => 'US',
);
$orders = wc_get_orders( $args );
```

Refer to
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query#address-and-name

Heres the duplicate post I answered .
[WooCommerce Shop Managers view orders on their specific Country costumer orders only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65260472/woocommerce-shop-managers-view-orders-on-their-specific-country-costumer-orders/65668654#65668654)