# WooCommerce Shop Managers view orders on their specific Country costumer orders only

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using a Country Based Restriction WooCommerce plugin that users can order only by their own country. I have 3 physical store branches in 3 countries, and now I created 3 Shop Manager roles 1 per country, and i want them to restrict on the order page only they can view the customer orders by their specific assigned country.

I found a similar question from here but still no answer [Show woocommerce orders by country](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45787428/show-woocommerce-orders-by-country)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to query orders by country. Here is a sample code.

```
// If you want to get orders from America.
$args = array(
    'billing_country' => 'US',
);
$orders = wc_get_orders( $args );
```

Refer to this doc.

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query#address-and-name

And for this question,

> I have 3 physical store branches in 3 countries, and now I created 3
> Shop Manager roles 1 per country, and i want them to restrict on the
> order page only they can view the customer orders by their specific
> assigned country.

I suggest creating a custom `shortcode` that **would query the Orders record**(use the code provided above) using the current country assigned to the current logged in `Shop Manager` (I suggest adding a user meta for the Shop Manager user where you can assign country code - e.g PH , US ) **and list**

Heres a snippet code.

```
$currentUserId = get_current_user_id();
$currentShopManagerCountryCode = get_user_meta($currentUserId ,"assigned_country_code",true);
$args = array(
    'billing_country' => $currentShopManagerCountryCode,
);
$orders = wc_get_orders( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

I made an experiment of this but I don't have any idea what I'm doing, I know this is wrong metas etc. hope you can help me to do this.

```
function view_order($order, $data, $view) {

        $country = $order->shipping_country;
        $shop_manager_id = '';

        $general_santos = ['GES'];
        $koronadal = ['KOR'];
        $polomolok = ['POL'];

        if (in_array($country, $general_santos)) {
            // Manually assigning the _store_manager_id using the user id, yours will differ
            $shop_manager_id = 5;
        } else if (in_array($country, $koronadal)) {
            $shop_manager_id = 3;
        } else if (in_array($country, $polomolok)) {
            $shop_manager_id = 2;
        } else {
            $shop_manager_id = 5;
        }

        $order->update_meta_data('_store_manager_id', $shop_manager_id);
    }
    add_action('woocommerce_view_order', 'view_order', 20, 2);
```