# WooCommece REST API - get orders by billing country

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to add a custom filter to a WooCommerce REST API 'orders' endpoint, something like:

`https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?billing_country=US`

My plugin is wrong - it returns an empty array.

```php
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_rest_shop_order_object_query', 'filter_orders_by_country_field', 999, 2 );
function filter_orders_by_country_field( $args, $request ) {
    if ( ! isset( $request['billing_country'] ) ) {
        return $args;
    }
    
    $source_value = sanitize_text_field( $request['billing_country'] );
    $source_meta_query = array(
        'key' => 'billing.country',
        'value' => $source_value
    );
    
    if ( isset( $args['meta_query'] ) ) {
        $args['meta_query']['relation'] = 'AND';
        $args['meta_query'][] = $source_meta_query;
    } else {
        $args['meta_query'] = array();
        $args['meta_query'][] = $source_meta_query;
    }
    
    return $args;
}
```

I want to get all orders by billing country.

I think I need to use `wc_get_orders( $args )`
like they say here: [WooCommerce Shop Managers view orders on their specific Country costumer orders only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65260472/woocommerce-shop-managers-view-orders-on-their-specific-country-costumer-orders/65668654#65668654)

It seems like it should be easy, but I've got nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong meta key. The one you need is *_billing_country*, not *billing.country* (there's no such a meta field in WooCommerce by default at all).

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_rest_shop_order_object_query', 'filter_orders_by_country_field', 999, 2 );
function filter_orders_by_country_field( $args, $request ) {
    if ( ! isset( $request['billing_country'] ) ) {
        return $args;
    }
    
    $source_value = sanitize_text_field( $request['billing_country'] );
    $source_meta_query = array(
        'key' => '_billing_country',
        'value' => $source_value
    );
    
    if ( isset( $args['meta_query'] ) ) {
        $args['meta_query']['relation'] = 'AND';
        $args['meta_query'][] = $source_meta_query;
    } else {
        $args['meta_query'] = array();
        $args['meta_query'][] = $source_meta_query;
    }
    
    return $args;
}
```

Comment: This is an improvement but now returns all of the orders  - there is still no filtering by billing country.

Comment: This is actually working now, not sure what I was doing wrong when I last tried it. Thanks!